# How to create an Azure Function that will POST to an Azure table?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have created a simple backend using Azure Easy Tables and I was wondering how I could use Azure Functions to perform CRUD. Right now I'm using the javascript client SDK and have it on my website but I know that this is not at all secure to say the least.

Currently, I'm using a triggered Azure Function to send emails. I then call this function from my website. I wanted to do the same for my CRUD operations. Any help is appreciated!

```
    module.exports = function (context, requ) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "EMAIL.API",
  "port": null,
  "path": "mail/send",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "AUTH",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify(
    { personalizations: 
   [ { to: [ { email: requ.query.email, name: requ.query.name } ],
       subject: 'AutoConscience Registration' } ],
  from: { email: 'noreply@conscience.ac', name: 'AutoConscience Support Team' },
  reply_to: { email: '', name: 'alcovesdev' },
  subject: 'AutoConscience Registration',
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use azure functions [native way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table) of writing to azure tables.

[Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#output---javascript-example) example.